# jenkins build git error tip Checking out files: Killed command terminated with exit code 137

Tags: git, jenkins, build

```
Started by GitLab push by topsystem
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (部署)
[Pipeline] node
Running on docker in /home/jenkins/workspace/rancher-topsystem-test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . roffe/kubectl:v1.13.2
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
docker seems to be running inside container 3ffc61d09ba2047cc871ec623a451a8660793d9c5f4a2bbc9bd4f395e83357e6
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 --entrypoint= -w /home/jenkins/workspace/rancher-topsystem-test --volumes-from 3ffc61d09ba2047cc871ec623a451a8660793d9c5f4a2bbc9bd4f395e83357e6 -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** roffe/kubectl:v1.13.2 cat
$ docker top 9cb300e8f05ddc82b72feef767d900ced41ed4d30832b25cb278d5795695267f -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $KUBERNETES_TOKEN
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
current branch: dev-customer-new-20221024
[Pipeline] writeFile
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [KUBERNETES_TOKEN]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ mkdir -p /root/.kube
+ echo ****
+ base64 -d
[Pipeline] sh
+ kubectl get deployments '--namespace=topsystem-test' dev-customer-new-20221024
NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dev-customer-new-20221024   1/1     1            1           42m
[Pipeline] sh
+ read pod ignore
+ grep repo-fetch-job
+ kubectl get pods '--namespace=topsystem-test-extra'
+ kubectl exec '--namespace=topsystem-test-extra' repo-fetch-job-7d66854b5b-4lrpp -- sh -c 'rm -f /topsystem.git/index; rm -f /topsystem.git/index.lock;git --git-dir=/topsystem.git gc;git --git-dir=/topsystem.git prune;find / -name index.lock |xargs rm -rf; GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git --git-dir=/topsystem.git fetch --all -p -f'
find: ‘/proc/1/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/49/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/50/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/57/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/58/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/60/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/61/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/116/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/117/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/118/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/119/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/8560/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/8584/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/8585/map_files’: Operation not permitted
Fetching origin
Warning: Permanently added '[frp-server.topsystem-system]:10022,[10.42.10.194]:10022' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
From ssh://frp-server.topsystem-system:10022/root/topsystem
   5656a6a92f..1034b21857  dev-customer-new-20221024 -> dev-customer-new-20221024
   74783fe752..6170f7b331  dev-upload-code-20221027  -> dev-upload-code-20221027
+ read pod ignore
[Pipeline] sh
+ kubectl get pods '--namespace=topsystem-test'
+ grep dev-customer-new-20221024
+ read pod ignore
+ kubectl exec '--namespace=topsystem-test' dev-customer-new-20221024-54cd786688-5n7q6 -- sh -c 'git reset --hard && git checkout -f dev-customer-new-20221024'
Checking out files:   3% (1256/34341)   
Killed
command terminated with exit code 137
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 9cb300e8f05ddc82b72feef767d900ced41ed4d30832b25cb278d5795695267f
$ docker rm -f 9cb300e8f05ddc82b72feef767d900ced41ed4d30832b25cb278d5795695267f
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 137
Finished: FAILURE
```

The submitted code will also fail to deploy

Even if the deployment is successful, there is a part of the code that is not deployed

I tried removing index.lock with no effect

[image]

No clue at all, any ideas to investigate? Is it a deployment script issue or something else

Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [KUBERNETES_TOKEN]
See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.

Warning: Permanently added

Comment: The "killed" really ought to show the signal that was used, otherwise this is potentially ambiguous. However, we might note that 128 + 9 = 137 and a killed process exits with 128-plus-signal-number as its status (plus the flag that says it was killed). Signal 9, meanwhile, is often from the ["OOM killer"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65577215/1256452). So your system is probably out of memory, even if it has plenty of memory (see linked question).